# Use Scientific Notation Recharts Y-Axis Scale

Tags: reactjs, recharts

My chart's y-axis is in scientific notation except for 1 tick only .. is it possible to adjust this in recharts? In particular the tick right before '1'. My data's range is from 1e-100 until 1.
I tried setting my own ticks but, for example 1e-1 gets displayed as 0.1.

```
                  <YAxis
                label=
                {{
                  value: "Collision Probability / -",
                  position: "insideLeft",
                  angle: -90,
                  dx: -3,
                  fill: "#808080",
                  dy: 70,
                  fontSize: "105%"
                }}
                scale="log"
                //@ts-ignore
                domain={['auto', '1']}
                type="number"
                dataKey="probability">
              </YAxis>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

```
                  <YAxis
                label=
                {{
                  value: "Collision Probability / -",
                  position: "insideLeft",
                  angle: -90,
                  dx: -3,
                  fill: "#808080",
                  dy: 70,
                  fontSize: "105%"
                }}
                scale="log"
                //@ts-ignore
                domain={domain.y}
                type="number"
                tickFormatter={(value) => Number(value.toFixed(10)).toExponential()}
                dataKey="probability">
              </YAxis>
```